# Magento 2: Installation issue

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.1.11

I am trying to install magento on my localhost and getting issue file installing set up.

Starting Magento installation:
                File permissions check...

```
            Required extensions check...

            Enabling Maintenance Mode...

            Installing deployment configuration...

            Installing database schema:
            [ERROR] PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:128
            Stack trace:
            #0 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(128): PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=in...', '', '', Array)
            #1 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
            #2 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(353): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
            #3 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_connect()
            #4 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT version(...', Array)
            #5 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(465): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT version(...', Array)
            #6 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(520): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('SELECT version(...', Array)
            #7 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('SELECT version(...', Array)
            #8 /var/www/html/m2111/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Validator/DbValidator.php(93): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne('SELECT version(...')
            #9 /var/www/html/m2111/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(1193): Magento\Setup\Validator\DbValidator->checkDatabaseConnection('', '', '', '')
            #10 /var/www/html/m2111/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(774): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->assertDbAccessible()
            #11 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSchema()
            #12 /var/www/html/m2111/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(344): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
            #13 /var/www/html/m2111/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
            #14 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction()
            #15 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
            #16 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
            #17 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
            #18 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
            #19 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
            #20 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
            #21 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
            #22 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
            #23 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
            #24 /var/www/html/m2111/setup/index.php(31): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
            #25 {main}

              Next Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:144
            Stack trace:
            #0 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
            #1 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(353): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
            #2 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_connect()
            #3 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT version(...', Array)
            #4 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(465): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT version(...', Array)
            #5 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(520): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('SELECT version(...', Array)
            #6 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('SELECT version(...', Array)
            #7 /var/www/html/m2111/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Validator/DbValidator.php(93): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne('SELECT version(...')
            #8 /var/www/html/m2111/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(1193): Magento\Setup\Validator\DbValidator->checkDatabaseConnection('', '', '', '')
            #9 /var/www/html/m2111/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(774): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->assertDbAccessible()
            #10 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSchema()
            #11 /var/www/html/m2111/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(344): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
            #12 /var/www/html/m2111/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
            #13 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction()
            #14 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
            #15 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
            #16 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
            #17 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
            #18 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
            #19 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
            #20 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
            #21 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
            #22 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
            #23 /var/www/html/m2111/setup/index.php(31): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
            #24 {main}

Next Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:144
    Stack trace:
 #0 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(353): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_connect()
#3 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT version(...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(465): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT version(...', Array)
 #5 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(520): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('SELECT version(...', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('SELECT version(...', Array)
 #7 /var/www/html/m2111/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Validator/DbValidator.php(93): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne('SELECT version(...')
 #8 /var/www/html/m2111/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(1193): Magento\Setup\Validator\DbValidator->checkDatabaseConnection('', '', '', '')
 #9 /var/www/html/m2111/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(774): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->assertDbAccessible()
 #10 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSchema()
 #11 /var/www/html/m2111/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(344): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
  #12 /var/www/html/m2111/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
  #13 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction()
 #14 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
 #15 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#16 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#17 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
 #18 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
  #19 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
  #20 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
   #21 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
  #22 /var/www/html/m2111/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#23 /var/www/html/m2111/setup/index.php(31): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#24 {main}
```

Comment: Have you verified that the files have 644 and folders 755?

Comment: Yes file permission is 755

Comment: check for any missing file , or db connectivity...

Answer (score 0):

Looking that error code I think this is just a connection error to **MySQL server**, or maybe a php version difference between web requests and CLI

More info http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_phpini.html

> This is commonly caused by a different instance of PHP being used by the PHP command line compared to the web server. In particular, mysql.sock might be misconfigured if this is the case.

Comment: I am using Above 7 and an set up already installed

Comment: Above 7, but... same version as CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because it can't connect to the database.

Could you add 'localhost' in Magento setup for database host? Please alo check once more that you've entered correct credentials for username and password.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise changing the host to "127.0.0.1" as well as ensuring that all your ports are open by closing every program that might be using them, e.g. Skype.